How do I stick an image to the top right of a screen in SwiftUI

so I am looking for how to stick this image to the top right portent of the screen. Should I use geometry reader and if so how would I implement that in my code.
Also the image is the (“SignInImage”)
Which is the person holding the phone
Image("OnBoardingBackground")
            
            VStack {
                Image("SignInImage")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
                Text("Get Started")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .fontWidth(.expanded)
                    .fontDesign(.monospaced)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Find community within your community")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .fontWidth(.standard)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .fontDesign(.monospaced)
                    .frame(width: 200)

                
                Divider()

That is a small snippet of what I have.
I have tried geometry reader several times but can't seem to get it to work properly. Honestly don't know what else to try.
sorry if there is an easy solution I just can't seem to find one and am relatively new to swiftui.

When you say "this image" which one do you mean? In your screenshot, things look good.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Stick image to the top right corner:
You need to replace:
Image(“SignInImage”)

to:
VStack {
   HStack {
       Spacer(minLength: 0)

       Image(“SignInImage”)
   }

   Spacer(minLength: 0)
}

and locate it inside of ZStack

Sorry I should’ve clarified in the post originally which I have changed but the image im wanting to move is the (“SignInImage”)

@Bengann just locate it inside ZStack :)
